# What does superscript of set $\Bbb N$ means?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

I am really new to set theory
 and i just encountered with this line

"Let $k\in \Bbb N$. A subset $A \subset \Bbb N_0^k$ is said to be a....."

However I am really confused what  $\Bbb N_0^k$ means , is that same as $\Bbb N$ with a limit to $k$ or  something ?

P.S - Novice here , So apologies for any inconvenience

Comment: Usually [$\mathbb N_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation) is the set of *natural* numbers starting from $0$.

Comment: $\mathbb N^{k}= \mathbb N \times \ldots \times \mathbb N$, with $k$ occurrences of $\mathbb N$, i.e. the set of all $k$-uples of natural numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Here $\mathbb N_0$ is the natural numbers with $0$, and $$\Bbb N_0^k=\underbrace{\Bbb N_0\times \dots \times \Bbb N_0}_{k\text{ times}}.$$

Comment: Don't forget to like and accept this answer, @MathFreak.